# Any difference between configure.ac and configure.in, and Makefile.am and Makefile.in?

Tags: makefile, autoconf, configure, automake

I have seen both in different things I have configured. What I the difference? Is it notable to use only one? Or does it not matter which one to use?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`configure.ac` and `configure.in` are two possible names for the master Autoconf source file, which is processed by `autoconf` to generate the `configure` shell script.  `configure.ac` is preferred for new packages, `configure.in` is an older name which still works.  (The `.in` suffix is now recommended to be used only for files which will be processed by `config.status`, which is the *result* of running `configure`.)

`Makefile.am` is an Automake source file.  Automake processes it and generates `Makefile.in`, which is then further processed by `config.status` to generate the final Makefile.  An Automake-generated `Makefile.in` is not meant to be edited by hand.  However, if a project doesn't use Automake (but does use Autoconf), then it will only have a `Makefile.in` which *is* hand-edited.

For further details see http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Making-configure-Scripts.html - particularly the diagrams.