# Adding post compile commands to autoconf C++ projects

Tags: c++, configure, autoconf

I have a few c++ projects that are built on Linux using autoconf. They were created by some predecessors of mine that are no longer with the company. I wish to create a separate debug symbols file for each binary.

1) I can easily do this on the command line using objcopy and strip, but what is the correct place to add them to the make so that they do not get overwritten should autoconf be run again?

2) Can I convert configure.in to configure.ac easily?

The projects have Makefile.am and configure.in files.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The way I do this is to build everything debug.  Then to get rid of symbols I `make DESTDIR=<somewhere> install-strip` to get the binaries without symbols

2) Yes.  It's just a file rename.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3783082/425738).

Comment: Thanks, will try this.